# "NoMethodError Table doesn't exist" in Rails 5 with PostGres disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a simple app to pull a json object from open nasa api.

This is my Model:

```
class Apod < ApplicationRecord
  def get_apod_info
    apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=#{ENV['NASA_API_KEY']}"
    response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(apod_url))
    JSON.parse(response)
  end
end
```

And this is my controller:

```
class ApodController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @apod_info = Apod.get_apod_info
  end
end
```

When I try to load the view in the browser, I get the error below at the bottom.

I have a database (I run db:create), but I'm not using it, so I have no schema and no migrations. But it sounds like this error might have something to do with the database?

I tried different things (even creating a migration with the model and running it), but I couldn't fix it. Similar error messages that I found online seem triggered by conditions different than mine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Processing by ApodController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


NoMethodError (undefined method `get_apod_info' for Apod(Table doesn't exist):Class):

app/controllers/apod_controller.rb:3:in `index'
  Rendering /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendering /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendering /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/aaa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method definition to

```
def self.get_apod_info
   /* code */
end
```

You are calling class method so add self in the method declaration

Answer (score 2):

If `Apod` isn't a database-backed model, then try using a plain old ruby object like (and yes, this should be a class method, not an instance method):

```
class Apod
  def self.get_apod_info
    apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=#{ENV['NASA_API_KEY']}"
    response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(apod_url))
    JSON.parse(response)
  end
end
```

Personally, I like this style:

```
class Apod
  class << self

    def get_apod_info
      apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=#{ENV['NASA_API_KEY']}"
      response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(apod_url))
      JSON.parse(response)
    end

  end
end
```

But, that's a matter of taste and I know some people don't like it.

Comment: Both answers are correct and solved the issue! Thank you.